# How to use 3 serial devices to get serial data in Python

Tags: ubuntu, serial-port

I have 3 `xbee` devices connected to `Intel NUC` which is running `Ubuntu 18.04`. I have 3 `systemd` services running in  ubuntu to get data from these 3 serial devices on port i.e. `ttyUSB0, ttyUSB1, ttyUSB2`. These services are

```
xbee-service1.service -> getting data from ttyUSB0 
xbee-service2.service -> getting data from ttyUSB1 
xbee-service3.service -> getting data from ttyUSB2
```

Everything is working perfectly fine but I have noticed after every 4-5 days, `xbee-service3.service` stops and it do not run. I try to keep restarting it but it fails. I checked the serial ports and all 3 serial ports are available but still service3 is in failed state. If I reboot the system, it still shows inactive running.

If I unplug the serial cable and plug it back and then after reboot, it then starts to operate normally. I have tried changing the cable but I am sure the issue is not with the cable.

Is there anything which block the serial port.? can anyone please guide me on how to properly use the ports and get data from all ports. Please help. Thanks

Output of cmd: `dmesg | grep tty`

```
[    0.000000] console [tty0] enabled
[    3.257776] usb 1-1: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now attached to ttyUSB0
[    3.259772] usb 1-2: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now attached to ttyUSB1
[    3.259979] usb 1-3: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now attached to ttyUSB2
```

Comment: Hello S, can you say what drivers are you running for those `tty` devices? I had this very same issue some time back and as far as I can remember it was driver-related.

Comment: @MarcosG. I don't know how to check. These are [xbee devices](https://www.google.com/search?q=xbee+devices&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiA1a7s_ejvAhUaSX0KHWpIDbYQ_AUoAnoECAEQBA&biw=1920&bih=969). Can you please tell me how to check the driver

Comment: You can just connect any of the devices or each of them if they are different and type `dmesg | grep tty` on the command line

Comment: @MarcosG. I have added the response of the cmd in question. Please have a look at it

Comment: it's and FTDI, same I had trouble with. Are you able to update the system completely or at least update the driver? I will take a look to see if I can find more details in my notes.

Comment: @MarcosG. When I run apt udpate command it executes fine. I will also check how we can update the driver. Thanks